# Proof regarding complex roots.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The question is as follows:

Let $C \in\mathbb {Z^+.}$ Prove that the complex roots of the equation $X^2 + X + \sqrt{C}=0$ are quadratic $\iff $ $C$ is a square in $\mathbb {Z}$.

I have attempted this question for quite some time without getting anywhere, my notes do not seem to be assisting me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @user26857, you need to show the roots are integral elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt D)$ where $D$ is a discriminant (it will be negative here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quadratic integers are roots of an equation $x^2+ax +b=0$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers.

If $C$ is an integer square the condition is automatically satisfied.

Conversely suppose that $X^2 + X + \sqrt{C}=0$ and $X^2+AX +b=0$. Subtracting we have $(A-1)X=\sqrt C-b $ and then $X$ would be real unless $A=1$ and $\sqrt C-b=0. $

Therefore $C=b^2$ as required.